# How do I load debugging symbols for a DLL in Visual C# Express 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing an app in Visual C# 2010 Express.  I want to step-into some code in a DLL to debug it.   The DLL and its whole source tree are on my same PC.    How do I load the symbols for it?

Googling for an answer says to use Debug > Windows > Modules when in run or debug mode.   But I don't see any option for Modules there and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx suggests that Express doesn't get a Modules Window.   So how should I load the symbols so I can step into my DLL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, that worked in this case, i.e. where the DLL build project was on my PC . . .

- Open the window for Tools > Options
- Check the checkbox in the lower left corner labeled "Show all
  Settings"
- From the tree view expand Debugging > Symbols window
- There's a multiline text box with a label "Symbol file (.pdb)
  locations:"
- To the right of that label a row of icons
- Click the icon that looks like a new folder icon; this will produce
  an empty edit line with a checkbox
- Type in the complete path of the folder where the .PDB file is to be
  found Check the checkbox and exit options.

  With this I was able to step through the code in the DLL and see variables.

Answer (score 0):

Debug -> Attach To Process and find the process that has loaded your .dll

Comment: I don't see an attach to process option under the Debug menu (Remember, this is Express), but in any case how would that help?  The process that's loaded the DLL is the process I'm already in.  The problem isn't finding the process; it's loading the symbols.